# Using nested routes with react-route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I have a few pages in my app that have their own menus, besides of course the main menu. I wish at every time that the sub-menu is clicked to render a different component.

I was told I could do that with react-routes, but it reaches a point where I get stuck and have no idea where to go from there. Here is a sample of my relevant current code:

```
   //app.js
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} handler={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
    <Route path="about" component={About}>
    </Route>
    <Route path="help" component={Help}>
        <Route path="help/:helpOption" component={HelpPanel}/>
    </Route>

   </Route>
  </Router>,
  destination
```

);

```
//help.js
export class HelpPanel extends Component{
render(){

        return (

            <div>{this.props.params.helpOption}</div>
        );
}
```

}

```
export class Help extends Component{
  render(){
     return (
         <Grid>
             <Title/>
             <Row className="show-grid">
               <Col lg={2} md={4} sm={4}>
                    <HelpMenu/>
               </Col>
               <Col lg={8} md={8} sm={8}>
                    {this.props.children || "Please select topic from the menu for more information"}
               </Col>

           </Row>
       </Grid>
   );
```

}
}

The `<HelpMenu/>` component is basically a side menu with all the options, and the things that appear on the `<HelpPanel/>` component changing depending on what option you chose.

[image]

I also drew what I would like my screen to look like, in case this post isn't clear.

The bottom line is, I cannot figure out for the life of me, how I can change what appears on HelpPanel depending on what menu option you chose.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 when trying to select an item on the menu? Setting `help/:helpOption` as the path I think will actually require the path to be `/help/help/:helpOption`

Comment: I'm not getting anything right now, just warnings that nothing matched my current route. Which for me is expected, because I don't know what and how to match things to my current route.

Comment: Error code 404 corresponds to no matching route, so I think the problem is that you're not setting the path for your `HelpPanel` correctly. Try changing the `path` from `help/:helpOption` to `/help/:helpOption`.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Okay, can you try changing the path to `:helpOption`? What *should* happen is that nested routes use the parent path as a prefix.

Comment: Are you not missing `<Link />` components in your help menu? How were you expecting the url to update?

Comment: @azium I'm not, they are in another part of the code that I simply didn't include here. I have those, but my question is how the heck am I supposed to use that to render different things in my <HelpPanel/> component?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've show as your route config, things looks sort of okay, but you haven't shown your Help Menu links. I suspect that along with the child route, is what is giving you issues:

```
<Route path="help" component={Help}>
   <Route path="help/:helpOption" component={HelpPanel}/>
</Route>
```

The `component` for each `:helpOption` should be that options component. So if you had a component called `HelpOptionOne` you would do this instead:

```
<Route path="help" component={HelpPanel}>
   <Route path="help/:helpOption" component={HelpOptionOne}/>
</Route>
```

If building a link for the `helpOption` it would look like this:

`<Link to="/help/help/optionOne">Option 1</Link>`

which is probably not what you want, but if you built the href that way, it would work. What you might want is:

```
<Route path="help" component={HelpPanel}>
   <Route path="/:helpOption" component={HelpOptionOne}/>
</Route>
```

which would then get your

`<Link to="/help/optionOne">Option 1</Link>`

Child routes take on their parent route in their path. You just have to remember that. [This is a good part of the documentation to read](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md).

Comment: I think I am missing something. I get how to render HelpOptionOne for example, but what about HelpOptionTwo, HelpOptionThree and etc? I cant understand where in the code I will differenciate what will appear for each option, if that makes sense. And that documentation doesn't make it clear unfortunately.